# How to place Facebook login to a multilingual website?

Tags: php, html, facebook

Briefly, my problem is the following: I have a website, on which people can log in with their Facebook account. The website is multilanguage. So when people have chosen their language, the site adapts. But in the English language,  login button does not appear. It should appear in 5 places as shown in the following code:

```
<body>
<?php 
if($_COOKIE["language"]=='hu') { 
$signin="Belépés";
$signout="Kilépés";
$home="Főoldal";
$about="Rólunk";
$contact="Kapcsolat";
$pages="Lapok";
$reg="Regisztráció";
$footer="© 2017 Tövis Krisztián. Minden jog fenntartva";
$who="Kik Vagyunk";
$submit="KÜLDÉS";
$male="fiú";
$female="lány";
$nameof="Tengerimalac neve";
$genderof="Tengerimalac neme";
$fillout="Kérlek töltsd ki a következő űrlapot, hogy megkapd első tengerimalacod!";
$weare="Mi vagyunk a legjobb Tengerimalac nevelde az interneten. Csak jelentkezz be Facebook fiókod segítségével és kezdd el nevelni saját online tengerimalacodat. Ingyenes!";
$readmore="Még Több";
$addgpig="<a class=sign href=# data-toggle=modal data-target=#myModal2>Új tengerimalac..</a>";
$mygpigs="<a href=myguineapig.php>Tengerimalacaim</a>";
$myshop="<a href=myshop.php>Bolt</a>";
$js="//connect.facebook.net/hu_HU/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.10&appId=****************";
 }
if($_COOKIE["language"]=='en' || $_COOKIE["language"]=='') { 
$signin="Sign In";
$signout="Sign Out";
$home="Home";
$about="About";
$contact="Contact";
$pages="Pages";
$reg="Registration";
$footer="© 2017 Krisztian Tovis. All Rights Reserved";
$who="Who We Are";
$submit="SUBMIT";
$male="male";
$female="female";
$nameof="Guinea pig's name";
$genderof="Guinea pig's gender";
$fillout="Please fill out the following form to get your first pet!";
$weare="We are the best online Guinea Pig nursery game on the internet. Just sign in with Facebook and start nursing your own online guinea pig. It's free!";
$readmore="Read More";
$addgpig="<a class=sign href=# data-toggle=modal data-target=#myModal2>New guinea pig..</a>";
$mygpigs="<a href=myguineapig.php>My guinea pigs</a>";
$myshop="<a href=myshop.php>Shop</a>";
$js="//connect.facebook.net/en_EN/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.10&appId=****************";
 } 
 ?>
 <script>
  // This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);
    // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
    // app know the current login status of the person.
    // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
    // for FB.getLoginStatus().
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // Logged into your app and Facebook.
      testAPI();
    } else {
                document.getElementById('statusbar').innerHTML =
        ' <a class="sign" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2"><i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo $signin; ?></a> ';
                        document.getElementById('statusbar2').innerHTML =
        ' <?php echo $signin; ?> ';
                        document.getElementById('statusbar3').innerHTML =
        ' <?php echo $signin; ?> ';
                        document.getElementById('statusbar4').innerHTML =
        ' <?php echo $signin; ?> ';
    }
  }

  // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
  // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
  // code below.
  function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '****************',
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                        // the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'v2.10' // use graph api version 2.8
  });

  // Now that we've initialized the JavaScript SDK, we call 
  // FB.getLoginStatus().  This function gets the state of the
  // person visiting this page and can return one of three states to
  // the callback you provide.  They can be:
  //
  // 1. Logged into your app ('connected')
  // 2. Logged into Facebook, but not your app ('not_authorized')
  // 3. Not logged into Facebook and can't tell if they are logged into
  //    your app or not.
  //
  // These three cases are handled in the callback function.

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });

  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "<?php echo $js; ?>";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
  // successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me?fields=id,cover,name,first_name,last_name,age_range,link,gender,locale,picture,timezone,updated_time,verified', function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
                document.getElementById('statusbar').innerHTML =
        ' <a class="sign" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2"><i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo $signout; ?></a> ';
                        document.getElementById('statusbar2').innerHTML =
        ' <?php echo $signout; ?> ';
                        document.getElementById('statusbar3').innerHTML =
        ' <?php echo $signout; ?> ';
                        document.getElementById('statusbar4').innerHTML =
        ' <?php echo $signout; ?> ';

                                document.getElementById('form').innerHTML =
        ' <br><?php echo $fillout; ?><br> \
        <form method="POST" action="get.php">   \
                        <input type=hidden name="fbid" value="'+ response.id +'"> \
                        <input type=hidden name="fbname" value="'+ response.name +'"> \
                        <input type=hidden name="fbfirstname" value="'+ response.first_name +'"> \
                        <input type=hidden name="fblastname" value="'+ response.last_name +'"> \
                        <input type=hidden name="fbgender" value="'+ response.gender +'"> \
                        <input type=hidden name="fblocale" value="'+ response.locale +'"> \
                        <input type="text" name="gpname" placeholder="<?php echo $nameof; ?>" required=""><br> \
                         <?php echo $genderof; ?>:<br> \
                         <select name="gpgender"> \
                         <option value="male"><?php echo $male; ?></option> \
                         <option value="female"><?php echo $female; ?></option> \
                         </select> \
                        <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $submit; ?>"> \
                        </form> ';

    });
  }
</script>
```

And the button should be appear here:

```
<div id="statusbar"></div>
<div id="statusbar2"></div>
<div id="statusbar3"></div>
<div id="statusbar4"></div>
<div id="statusbar5"></div>
```

Comment: Do you want to solve this using JavaScript or php?  This looks like a PHP question so you should probably remove the JavaScript tag.

Comment: Any errors in browser console? Have you checked the generated HTML code, does that look ok?